# Do RuBisCo and Haemoglobin have any similarity?

Tags: biochemistry

In RuBisCo and haemoglobin both can bind to CO<sub>2</sub> as well as O<sub>2</sub>. Do these proteins have any structural similarity?

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged "human-biology"? 2. Did you just wiki these proteins up?

Comment: No I was reading photosynthesis in NCERT where I found that RuBisCo also accepts CO2 and O2 and so the question came in my mind..!

Comment: I deleted "In plants" at the start of your question as there is no haemoglobin in plants. (There is leghaemoglobin, but, although structurally related, it’s not the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading about these proteins. Apart from wikipedia, you can check out [pfam](http://pfam.xfam.org/) which classifies proteins into families. [Globins](http://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF00042) and [RuBisCO](http://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF00016) are very different protein families. Perhaps the only similarity is that both these are made up of amino acids!

Comment: Isn't Pfam classification a bit too advanced for someone reading grade 10 textbooks? :P

Comment: @KoustavPal No, I don't think it is that difficult (the summary page at least). Plus, RuBisCO is probably not introduced in 10th grade. I remember it was 11th. The question is a closure candidate on the grounds of "homework" without an effort. I didn't VTC because the OP is probably a highschooler.